# How to avoid multiple calls to a REST API?

Tags: rest

Suppose I have a REST API and I can fetch the list of my friends and the favorite songs of each friend in my list. Now I want to fetch all favorite songs of all my friends. The problem with REST API is that I can't do that just using only one request. I must make a request to get my friends and then do a request for each friend.

I have read about the framework that I don't remember the name that permit to do that in only one request.

Do you know an idea about the technology that can do that?

Comment: software recommendations are explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic] (it's the same here as at Stack Overflow). See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: Why not make a route /user/me/friends/songs and then return the list of friends with each of their songs. or return just a list of their songs.

Comment: @gnat I'm not searching a framework but the technology. I  changed my question.

Comment: @MichaelMalura yes I can do that but there's cases when you can't find a solution like that. For example if there's many relations

Comment: It's all a [breeze](http://www.getbreezenow.com/) when you know what you're after. Basically an ORM over REST.

Answer (score 0):

Right now I am using [Spring](https://spring.io/) in order to handle the REST calls. It works with Java-Annotations and can also convert the objects you are returning to [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/) on the fly.

I think it is pretty convenient to use so far and it works well in combination with [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) (ORM).

For example:

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

Will give you the output:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "content": "Hello, World!"
}
```

But just take a look at [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/).

**To avoid multiple calls** you could just pass all necessary parameters in one call and simply return a list of friends and their songs. Processing large data is another thing [Spring can do for you](http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/10932_3858976_2/Use-Spring-Batchs-Chunk-Processing-for-Large-Data-Sets.htm).

**EDIT:**

Reading over your question again I am not sure if what you wanted is a technology for REST calls or if you just need a powerful ORM tool. In that case, like mentioned before, Hibernate is a very powerful tool. It has its learning curve but I think it's worth it. If you go for Hibernate **[definitely take a look at this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4AFF701184976B25)**!